# User and Account management in a distributed system

Tags: microservices, soa

we have a big distributed and multitenant system with all sorts of accounts :
 - admin and backoffice users account
 - customer account
 - cashier  account (tenant : there is one or many more cashier for each client tenant)

All this account are sharing more or less the same lifecycle (account created, grant on some ressources, deny account, password reminder...) 
But they are not used in all applications of the system : some account would be used on specific or just two application for example.
 Furthermore our system should have the possibility to have a bridge with a CMS for the customer management, or the backoffice users account could be authorized one day against a ldap...

So the question : we are searching for the best way to model our right and authorization service(s).
One idea is to create one service in order to manage all types of accounts of any kind : that is a SOA way to modularize our system
And one idea is to create different services : perhaps much more a micro-service oriented way of thinking...

What are your opinion ? I am searching some advices and feedback on this two different approach or perhaps an alternative that we habve not thought about...

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for any open-source solution for your problem, you can have a look into [keyclaok](https://www.keycloak.org/).

Keycloak also got place in [Thoughtworks Technology RADAR](https://www.thoughtworks.com/radar/platforms/keycloak). 
It is very promising solution and has LDAP, Multi Tenancy support also. checkout [keycloak features](https://www.keycloak.org/docs/2.5/server_admin/topics/overview/features.html).

There is paid solution like [ForgeRock](https://www.forgerock.com/) is also avaible.

Coming to feedback which you have asked about SOA or microservice way of implementation here (You will get different feedback/advice on this)

It will be better if you have a service to take care of access and authorization management and other to look into user details. If you meant that having different services for different account then note that Having one service for taking care account is still considered as Microservice approach as there is one dedicated service to perform single set of tasks.

You can have User-Service for user information management and a authService to handle access and authorization of users. [check](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44886715/should-the-auth-server-be-combined-with-the-user-service-in-a-microservices-arch).